# SQL Server : EXISTS (SELECT INTO)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 queries. If the first one returns empty set, I execute the second query, and if it returns empty set too, I give to the server the last chance and do the third:

```
SELECT ... INTO #Query1
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Query1)
    SELECT * FROM #Query1
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT ... INTO #Query2
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Query2)
    SELECT * FROM #Query2
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    END
END
```

It worked well, but I've faced a new task - the query should be used as a subquery as well as other queries, within `IF EXISTS([subquery])`. Doing this, I see

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

How should I modify the original query to meet this new condition?

Regards,

Comment: You can use @@ROWCOUNT to check if the previous SELECT statement affected any rows.  Can you clarify the question a little?  You want to place data into different temporary tables, but then use something in a subquery?  There may be a user-defined function that returns a table in your future.

Comment: You have managed to explain what you are doing but what you want to do instead is not that clear. It would be good if you could elaborate on that and please show the query that gives you the syntax error.

Comment: To user92546: @@ROWCOUNT doesn't help, since I cannot do the following query. IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table A IF @@rowcount = 0 SELECT 2) SELECT 3

Comment: To Mikael Eriksson. Obviously, I want to modify the original query to keep it valid as a standalone query, that does exactly what it did, but also make it valid as a subquery for IF EXISTS(...). The other subqueries are simple SELECTs, so if I have to use something else instead of IF EXISTS(...), this emptiness  checking expression should handle them as well.

Comment: SELECT INTO cannot have the same source and destination tables.  Are you sure you want to select from #Query1 into #Query1 if #Query1 contains rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
create function dbo.Foo()
  returns @Result table ( ThingId Int, Source Int )
as
begin
  insert into @Result
    select ThingId, 1 as Source from Things1
  if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    insert into @Result
      select ThingId, 2 as Source from Things2
  if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    insert into @Result
      select ThingId, 3 as Source from Things3
  --...
  return
end
go
select * from dbo.Foo()
select 42 as 'The Answer' where exists ( select * from dbo.Foo() where Source > 9 )
```

You can pass parameters into the function to use in WHERE clauses and the like.  The Source column may be omitted if you don't care to know where the data originated.